# How to remove bootstrap dropdown container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

[image: the issue]

As described in the image, I am attempting to get rid of the transparent container around the dropdown options. I've attempted multiple CSS solutions that have not worked. Here is the HTML code for the dropdown:

```js
      $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(250);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(105)
  });
```

```html
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>

        <li><a href="#home" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about-section" class="page-scroll">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services-section" class="page-scroll">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact-section" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you add some CSS? maybe a link of the template that you are using? or other stuffs?

Comment: Yup. The solution provided worked great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So is it the container's shadow you don't want? If so you can alter the `.dropdown-menu` class css by adding something like

```
.dropdown-menu {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

If this doesn't work add `!important` before the `;` on the properties that aren't disappearing, like so:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    border: none !important;
    /* etc... */
}
```